# how to read from a combobox but write to a specific range of cells within excel

Tags: vba

I'm trying to get info  from  multiple comboboxes and place them in a 
another sheet. I was able to do it if I change the columns to 1,2,3,4... etc..

but I am having difficulty trying to start the data in 8,9,10... then repeat on the next row.

I think I must be missing something small.. hopefully.

The code below fills the row once, but when I ran again it writes over it.
but If I change the columns to 1,2,3,4.... it writes the next row ... again the next row.

I'm not sure how to make it write the next row when I want the data to start population in H2.

Is there something I can add to make it write to the next row each time this runs H3, H4, H5?  - fyi this needs to work for up to 3,000 rows.

```
Private Sub Submit_Click()
Dim lRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("EvaluationTable")

lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

' If Range("H2").Value = "" Then
' starts with H2 fills in values from combobox left to right on
  With ws
    .Cells(lRow, 8).Value = Me.CMB1.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 9).Value = Me.CMB2.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 10).Value = Me.CMB3.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 11).Value = Me.CMB4.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 12).Value = Me.CMB5.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 13).Value = Me.TextBox1.Text
   End With

'If Range("H2").Value > "" Then
' With ws
 ' ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Select
 '  .Cells(lRow, 8).Value = Me.CMB1.Value
  '  .Cells(lRow, 9).Value = Me.CMB2.Value
  '  .Cells(lRow, 10).Value = Me.CMB3.Value
   ' .Cells(lRow, 11).Value = Me.CMB4.Value
   ' .Cells(lRow, 12).Value = Me.CMB5.Value
 '  End With
 Unload Me

'End If
' End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This an easy way to get the data from the comboboxes to a worksheet:

```
Option Explicit    
Sub TestMe()    
    Dim cnt         As Long
    Dim startFrom   As Long   

    startFrom = 10        
    For cnt = 1 To 3
        Cells(startFrom + cnt, 1) = OLEObjects("ComboBox" & cnt).Object.Value
    Next cnt    
End Sub
```

Here you start from the first ComboBox and you go up to the third one.

---

If the comboboxes are on a form (as I guess from the usage of `Me.`, this is a working way to do it, following the same logic from above:

```
Private Sub Submit_Click()    
    Dim cnt As Long
    Dim startFrom As Long

    startFrom = 10
    For cnt = 1 To 3
        Cells(startFrom + cnt, 1) = Me.Controls("ComboBox" & cnt).Value
    Next cnt
End Sub
```

Comment: I like that, haven't used objects like that before.. as you can probably tell I'm pretty new. I'll definitely look into that.  ah ok  Controls..

Comment: Hi thank you so much for the help.  found out what the problem was it was my last row ... this is the one that ended up working still figuring out how it is working... but thought I would share lRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1   ' apparently newer versions of excel don't like the old method  also added activecell(offset).... to help it to start within the With section.